# different results of IN Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Don't quite understand IN statement. First variant works fine:

```
select manufacturers.id
from manufacturers
where manufacturers.id in (select manufacturerId 
                           from pcs group by manufacturerId 
                           having count(manufacturerId) > 1)
```

But when I make subquery a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Get_manufacturers @productType varchar(50)  
as 
begin   
declare @query varchar(500)   
set @query='select manufacturerId from ' +  QuoteName(@productType) + ' 
               group by manufacturerId having count(manufacturerId) > 1'   
declare @t table (manufacturerId int)
insert into @t exec(@query)
select manufacturerId from @t;
end


select manufacturers.id
from manufacturers
where manufacturers.id in (Get_manufacturers 'pcs')
```

I get an error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'pcs'

Get_manufacturers 'pcs' works properly. Where am I wrong?

Comment: That is not how stored procedures work, so you code just makes no sense whatsoever.  You can think about making a stored function.  However, in SQL Server, those cannot use dynamic SQL.  In other words, if you want a stored procedure, you need to insert the results into a table and then use that table in the query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff. OK. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Get_manufacturers 'pcs' works properly - it returns a table. I suspect I don't understand IN condition.

Comment: No, procedures do not return tables, select in a procedure returns a resultset. You need table valued function for the task https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Microsoft Management Studio shows absolutely equal results in case of (select manufacturerId 
                           from pcs group by manufacturerId 
                           having count(manufacturerId) > 1) and (Get_manufacturers 'pcs')

Comment: Yes, SSMS is a client which interacts with a server the way you directed it to interact and shows what it's designed to show.

Comment: You've basically designed yourself into a corner here. The root cause of this really is that you appear to have one table per product type? This does not solve your immediate issue but it serves to illustrate why things should not be designed this way. The issue isn't obvious when you start, only when you try and do more advanced functions.

Comment: Use a **table-valued user-defined function** instead of the stored procedure:- then you will be able to use it like your example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't quite understand IN statement
>
> ...
>
> Get_manufacturers 'pcs' works properly - it returns a table

You misunderstand both `stored procedures` and `IN` condition.

From [IN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql):

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN   
    ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]  
    )
```

What the stored procedure returns is not a subquery, neither it's an expression.
Here is a link to understand what subquery is [Using a Subquery in a T-SQL Statement](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3464481/Using-a-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm)

> A subquery is a SELECT statement that is nested within another T-SQL
> statement

So stored procedure is not a subquery, it's just not a SELECT statement.
But even when you say that stored procedures returns a table it's wrong: you can JOIN a table to another table but you cannot join the result of stored procedure.
And even if you "see" the result set returned by a procedure as a "table" it's not a table.

Comment: Well. What to do?

Comment: If all you want to do is to use a different table name in the query from original post, just use dynamic SQL. You can wrap it in a stored procedure (the whole thing, not just a subquery) or maybe you do not need dynamic code at all, if you can precise what you try to achieve there can be another solutions

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rokuto and Gordon Linoff suggestions, Alter the procedure by omitting the table declaration:

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].Get_manufacturers @productType nvarchar(50)  
            as 
            begin   
            declare @query nvarchar(500)   
            set @query= N'select manufacturerId from ' +  QuoteName(@productType) + ' 
                           group by manufacturerId having count(manufacturerId) > 1'   
            ---declare @t table (manufacturerId int)
            ---insert into @t exec(@query)
            ---select manufacturerId from @t;
            exec(@query)
            end
            GO
```

Then, Use a temporary table to fill in the results of the stored procedure.

```
            IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_manufacturers') IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #tmp_manufacturers
            END

            CREATE TABLE #tmp_manufacturers
            (
               manufacturerId int
            )

            INSERT INTO #tmp_manufacturers (manufacturerId)
            EXEC dbo.Get_manufacturers 'pcs'
```

lastly, add it to your IN condition.

```
            select m.id
            from manufacturers M
            where m.id IN (select t.manufacturerId From #tmp_manufacturers T)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff said, procedures does not return tables.
But, if you want to store output data from stored procedures, you need to put it into table e. g.:

```
DECLARE @manufactures TABLE (Id int)
INSERT INTO @manufactures
exec Get_manufacturers 'pcs'

select manufacturers.id
from manufacturers
where manufacturers.id IN (SELECT Id FROM @manufactures)
```

Instead of table variable, you can use temporary table.

Comment: Error: Procedure Get_manufacturers, Line 7
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

Comment: @IgorSeliverstov AS you can see, your procedure is invalid. I don't know why you are doing this in that way, but check if you replace `declare @t table (manufacturerId int) insert into @t exec(@query) select manufacturerId from @t;` with simple `exec(@query)` will help (without inserting data into table in procedure).